# find a string in a text file and copy finded string into a variable value in cmd

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, copy, findstr

I want search in the text file  and copy contents in value of variable my text file name is pass and that's content is only    123 i want var value be 123

```
set var=123
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your goal. Do you want to search the text file for "123"? If you find "123" in the text file, what should be done?

Comment: i have a text file With Content (ex.123) and i have a Variable Namely var . i want var =123

Comment: Do you want `SET "V=123" & FIND "%V%" file.txt`?

Comment: yes i want find v value from file.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
REM write to file:
(echo 123)>pass
REM read from file:
<pass set /p var=
REM display value:
echo %var%
```

this reads the first (or only) line of the file.